# How to extract inner text inside p tag from Selector in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I use css selector to retrieve p tags and I'm trying to extract text from first p tag. But it is always html content including p tag.
Here is my code.

```py
section_div = response.css('div[data-testid="talent-profile-page-talent-info"]')
p_names = section_div.css("section#talent-summary >p")
name = p_names[0].extract()
```

Here is the p tag html:
`<p color="inherit" class="Text-sc-1d6qffq-0 eBczUW">Bob Guiney</p>`

Of course, I know there is other ways to get the inner text but I want to get it done this way.

Is there any function to get only inner text from Selector? I need to get only **Bob Guiney**

This is what I tried but it only works when there isn't any other tag in side the section.

```
p_names = section_div.css("section#talent-summary >p::text")
name = p_names[0].get()
```

Comment: Try this `p_names = section_div.css("section#talent-summary >p::text")`

Ref: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=get#extensions-to-css-selectors

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CFCIFE . What about second p tag?

Comment: You can do `p_names = section_div.css("section#talent-summary >p*::text")` instead and it should return a list of all the inner texts

Answer (score 0):

To select the inner text you can use the `::text` pseudo-element.

So you will have to update code to

```
p_names = section_div.css("section#talent-summary > p::text")
```

and this will extract the text content from the p tag.

If there are multiple p tags then you can use `get()`

```
name = p_names[n].get()
```

where the index is the number that starts from 0 for the first p tag to n that is the nth p tag that you want to get data from.

Comment: Thanks for your message but I want the inner text of second p tag.

Comment: Then you can use name = p_names[1].get(). I edited my response so you can follow that.

Comment: It does not work if there are other tags inside the section.